# AWS4 Signing request signature does not match…even though it seems to

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, momentjs

I appear to have correctly followed the procedure for generating a canonical string and string to sign for the AWS4 SDK. However I receive the error **The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.**

The only clue I have is that when I'm not using the Moment.js utc() call, it accepts the signature as a match but (as expected) treats the signature as expired, so I suspect the UTC vs. local time is related to the issue.

Here is the code where I generate the timestamps.

```
var now = moment().utc();
var date_stamp = now.format('YYYYMMDD');
var amzn_date = now.format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ');
var string_to_sign_date = now.format('YYYYMMDDTHHmmssZ');

string_to_sign_date = string_to_sign_date.replace('+00:00', 'Z');
amzn_date = string_to_sign_date.replace('+00:00', 'Z');
```

Here is where I create the string_to_sign:

```
var string_to_sign = connectMeRequest.algorithm + '\n' + string_to_sign_date + '\n' + credential_scope + '\n' + cryptoJS.SHA256(canonical_request);
```

Here is my (console logged) vs. Amazon's signature. I didn't replace the newlines in their JSON res in case that is the issue.

My output for **canonical string**:

```
  POST
/prod/makeEchoCallHandler

content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
host:408wm9ltub.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
x-amz-date:20160116T191451Z
x-amz-target:aws4_request

content-type;host;x-amz-date;x-amz-target
03a2c439264740e4883441d0049beaf9da4dc865ddd7169dbe9e747f28da6185
```

Their output:

```
 POST\n/prod/makeEchoCallHandler\n\ncontent-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded\nhost:408wm9ltub.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com\nx-amz-date:20160116T191451Z\nx-amz-target:aws4_request\n\ncontent-type;host;x-amz-date;x-amz-target\n03a2c439264740e4883441d0049beaf9da4dc865ddd7169dbe9e747f28da6185
```

My output for **string to sign**:

```
AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
20160116T191451Z
20160116/us-west-2/execute-api/aws4_request
ab63b72a190addcde39771097bbbc2e28c0d00c458fda9136d2d630e227e9074
```

Their output:

```
AWS4-HMAC-SHA256\n20160116T191451Z\n20160116/us-west-2/execute-api/aws4_request\nab63b72a190addcde39771097bbbc2e28c0d00c458fda9136d2d630e227e9074
```

Answer (score 1):

The '\n' is officially part of the string to sign. You need to add it in explicitly. A good example is [found here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-create-string-to-sign.html). The important part is:

```
StringToSign  =
Algorithm + '\n' +
RequestDate + '\n' +
CredentialScope + '\n' +
HashedCanonicalRequest
```

Add those in and give it another try!

**EDIT:** As noted in the comments, this looks to be an error in the date formatting between the canonical string and the string to sign.

Comment: Ok, I think your line in the canonical string is wrong: ```x-amz-date:2016-01-14T19:56:12```. Change this to ```x-amz-date:20160114T195612Z```

Comment: Good catch, made that change to the signature generator and updated above. Still the same error however.

Comment: It looks like the format is still wrong above. You need to use the same date format that you use in the string to sign.

Comment: Ah interesting!……just noticing that the UTC process does format one of those dates differently. Okay, let me investigate a bit further. Will come back and accept your answer assuming no further oddness pops up.

Comment: Unfortunately, even with those fixes, I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: The date you have above is *still* wrong. You have ```x-amz-date:20160115T152859+00:00``` and should have ```x-amz-date:20160115T152859Z```. Every single piece must be identical for v4 signing to work. Also, the two dates between the canonical and string to sign are different. They need to be the same as well.

Comment: *sigh*, such are the flaws of working too fast. I updated once again. This time it looks like a perfect match.